# C fastest way to compare two bitmaps

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

There are two arrays of bitmaps in the form of char arrays with millions of records. What could be fastest way to compare them using C.

I can imagine to use bitwise operator xor 1 byte at a time in a for loop.

Important point about bitmaps:

- 1% to 10% of times algorithm is run, bitmaps can differ. Most of the time they will be same. When hey can differ, they can as much as 100%. There is high probability of change of bits in continuous streak.
- Both bitmaps are of same length.

Aim:

- Check do they differ and if yes then where.
- Be correct every time (probability of detecting error if there is one should be 1).

Comment: Could you post your current best method?

Comment: So you benchmarked it and you concluded that this was the bottleneck, right?

Comment: I would trust `memcmp` to be optimized for your processor.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Added. Xor single byte in for loop.

Comment: Using the processor word size will likely be faster than bytes. Try doing it in `int`-sized chunks. Profiling should show some improvement.

Comment: Is the purpose to find identical bitmaps? How large are the bitmaps and how many do you expect to have?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the images? Will the images either be completely different or the same, for instance? More generally, by how much do you expect images being compared to differ?

Comment: @Patrick87 Added those details.

Comment: @TAS bitmaps have millions of bits. I aim to find whether they are identical or not.

Comment: With SSE intrinsics or without?

Comment: What percentage of words (say, 32 bits) will differ? Knowing 1% to 10% of bits differ is a good start, but this could translate into 1% to 100% of words being different, depending on how the differing bits are distributed.

Comment: @harold What does SSE stand for ?

Comment: @Patrick87 I made a mistake here. 1% to 10% of times bitmaps can differ. They can differ as much as 100% but when there is high probability of change in bits in continuous streak. I will add this point.

Comment: Streaming SIMD Extensions. They would allow you to compare 16 bytes at once, OR a bunch of those comparisons, and then, for example, only branch twice for every block of 64 bytes (one branch for the loop, one exit-branch if there were any unequal bytes in the 64byte block). But it's target specific, of course.

Comment: OK, one final question. When bitmaps differ, what's the probability that a given word in bitmap1 will differ from the corresponding word in bitmap2? Basically, if the images are either the same image or totally unrelated, we could put the probability of corresponding words being the same at 1/(2^32), a rather low figure. If that's the problem you're trying to solve, you could solve this problem to a high degree of certainty simply by trying a few words, possibly arbitrarily selected from a large bitmap. If they're all the same, the odds are astronomically in favor of the images being the same.

Comment: @Patrick87 Bitmaps represent same set of data. Target here to be computational fastest and give 100% accurate results.

Comment: If the bitmaps represent the same data, how can they be different? What do you mean by that? If you want 100% accurate results and there are no constraints on how different different images are, if one bit in in the 100,325,136th word can be different and your algorithm needs to detect this, then you had better plan on using `memcmp`. Most applications do not require 100% accuracy, especially given the imprecise nature of bitmap data (if it represents a photograph, for instance, odds are the pixels are just aggregate values anyway.)

Comment: @Patrick87 Bitmaps represent same data. One is kind of a backup and other gets corrupt. Imagine (some sort of security algorithm) a case were former is used to detect whether data got corrupted or not.

Comment: OpenCV is perhaps more suited for such stuff.

Comment: What information do you want to know when you do the comparison?  Do you just need to know that they are the same or that they differ, or do you need to know where they differ, or how many bits are different, or ... what?  Are they always the same length?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, added to description. Later part in your description.

Comment: Performance is bullshit. A `memcmp()` (or similar loop) will effectively saturate the memory bus. Most of the time will be spent waiting for the cache lines to fill.

Comment: @wildplasser even if done in smaller chunks depending on resources offered by device? Any suggestions.

Comment: Smaller chunks won't reduce the total amount of data needed. And I don't know what you mean by _device_ . (I also suggest that you create two versions of your program/function, and **benchmark** these; before jumping to conclusions)

Comment: @wildplasser Makes sense. Next week I plan to write solutions and benchmark them. Will update here with code and results and see whether they solve anything. By device I meant different architectures with varying resources.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes you mean 'bitmap' as a sequence of 0/1 values rather than 'bitmap image format'

If you simply have two bitmaps of the same length and wish to compare them quickly, `memcmp()` will be effective as someone suggested in the comments. You could if you want try using SSE type optimizations, but these are not as easy as `memcmp()`. `memcmp()` is assuming you simply want to know 'they are different' and nothing more.

If you want to know how many bits they are different by, e.g. 615 bits differ, then again you have little option except to XOR every byte and count the number of differences. As others have noted, you probably want to do this more at 32/64 or even 256 bits at a time, depending on your platform. However, if the arrays are millions of bytes long, then the biggest delay (with current CPUs) will be the time to transfer main memory to the CPU, and it wont matter terribly what the CPU does (lots of caveats here)

If you question is more asking about comparing A to B, but really you are doing this lots of times, such as A to B and C,D,E etc, then you can do a couple of things

- A. Store a checksum of each array and first compare the checksums, if these are the same then there is a high chance the arrays are the same. Obviously there is a risk here that checksums can be equal but the data can differ, so make sure that a false result in this case will not have dramatic side effects. And, if you cannot withstand false results, do not use this technique.
- B. if the arrays have structure, such as they are image data, then leverage specific tools for this, how is beyond this answer to explain.
- C. If the image data can be compressed effectively, then compress each array and compare using the compressed form. If you use ZIP type of compression you cannot tell directly from zip how many bits differ, but other techniques such as RLE can be effective to quickly count bit differences (but are a lot of work to build and get correct and fast)
- D. If the risk with (a) is acceptable, then you can checksum each chunk of say 262144 bits, and only count differences where checksums differ. This heavily reduces main memory access and will go lots faster.

All of the options A..D are about reducing main memory access as this is the nub of any performance gain (for problem as stated)

Comment: I like the idea of breaking the image into chunks and checksumming the chunks, then comparing the checksums. Unfortunately that can only tell you that the images are unequal, there's always a possibility that images with the same checksums aren't the same. You need to do a second comparison on all the bits to be sure. Given that the OP says the images will be equal over 90% of the time this optimization might actually be slower.

Comment: @mark ransom. I've expanded the warning about this to be more explicit, you are correct you really only want to do this method if very occasional false results wont affect things tooo much. Thnx.

Comment: @rlb this one needs to accurate every time. Updated question with that info. Thanks