# C - Fastest Way to OR two bitmaps

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Very similar to this question: [C fastest way to compare two bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240459/c-fastest-way-to-compare-two-bitmaps)

However I want to have a returned bitmap (a literal sequence of 0/1 values most likely represented with a char *) that is the bitwise OR of the two of them? None of the mem___ seem to make sense here?

Bitmaps are guaranteed to be the same size. I'd like to store the result of the bitwise OR as well so the resulting bitmap needs to be accessible. Size of bitmaps are in the magnitude of 10^5 bytes.

```
long * a = (long *) getByteBufferData();
long * b = (long *) getByteBufferData(); //these return different pointers
for(int i = 0; i < SystemByteSize , i++){
 a[i] = a[i] | b[i];
}
```

Comment: What is bitmaps are different sizes? What do you want to happen? You need to be way more clear about what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: You haven't put any array size conditions on this. So the simple answer is, if the bitmaps are represented as byte arrays in memory, to go through with a `for` or `while` loop and use the C bitwise OR operator (`|`). The `mem___` functions mentioned in your link only referred to comparison. Note was made of an XOR, but assuming the simple looping as I mentioned.

Comment: @lurker I don't have any performance conditions except for speed. Bitmaps are 10^5 bytes in magnitude.

Comment: `10^5` isn't a huge number of bytes. If they're organized as int instead of char, then doing a `for` loop should be pretty quick. Have you tried it?

Comment: @lurker can you elaborate on why they should be organized as int instead of char? sorry if that's a dumb question. The function that I'm using to fetch the bitmaps in the first place returns them as char *  so that's why I specified that.

Comment: `10^5` bytes can be 100000 `unsigned char` or 25000 `unsigned long`. Looping through 25000 `unsigned long` values takes less time than 100000 byte values (on a 32 bit CPU). Even though they're `char *` you could still pull in 2 or 4 bytes at a time into a 32-bit value. However, I really think you need to run a couple of timing tests using loops. The loop is very simple. It probably takes less time to write and try the code than to talk about it. :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I just really wanted to make sure I wasn't missing out on anything obvious that would boost performance.

Comment: If you put a complete example of your implementation in your question, we give specific advice on how to make it faster if necessary.

Comment: @Ryan it's literally 2 function calls that I don't have access to that return two separate char * that I want to set the first char * bitmap to the bitwise OR of both of them. I'm not sure if there's any useful information there

Comment: @knowads: No, I mean implement the function with just a straightforward loop and post that if you need optimization advice.

Comment: @Ryan  I mean I don't know how you optimize a loop but I added it anyway.

Comment: @knowads: Okay. First, don’t cast the return values; your compiler will probably optimize to operate on bigger blocks anyway, but casting `char*` to `long*` breaks strict aliasing, as well as alignment on some platforms. It might also help the compiler if you add `restrict` to the declarations of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix the loop limit (byte size of buffer / sizeof long) and ensure the buffers are `long`-aligned, you can be sure that the compiler will do a good job of optimizing this.  For x86, even old versions of gcc will use SSE instructions to `or` 16 bytes at a time.

A concise way to write the function in C is:

```
void or(unsigned long *r, unsigned long *x, unsigned n) {
  while (n--) *r++ |= *x++;
}
```

[Here's gcc 4.8 output](http://gcc.parallella.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22AQ4NwewSwE2CBOAKArgOwM5QOZoKZwA2Ea2wAVAgDTDpa4HDGkUAeNdO%2BcaAlMAG8AUKFAB3ABZRCeYEjQBaBf0oBqVcAA%2BAXjbqA3CNABfIAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g48%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O4%22%7D%5D%7D) at -O4. It may be possible to do better with hand-crafted assembly language aimed at a specific processor, but not much.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great response. Should I cast the result of my getByteBufferData function to a long * from a char *?

Comment: @knowads Only if you know for sure the buffer is word aligned. If it's not, performance will suffer as a minimum. On some machines, you'll get a memory fault.  Safest is to just use `char *` types for the arguments. Gcc will "or" byte by byte until the next 16 byte boundary, use SSE instructions as far as possible in 16-byte blocks, then finish up the last few bytes one-by-one. Gcc v7 even unrolls the initial loop: https://godbolt.org/g/umxdN4